# [Angular]: How to show exact component using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

In my project I have following template`

```
<div class="footer-wrapper__fm">
    <app-footer-type1
      *ngIf="configService.defaultOptions.ConfigsNew.FooterType === 'Type1')">
    </app-footer-type1>
    <app-footer-type2
      *ngIf="configService.defaultOptions.ConfigsNew.FooterType === 'Type2'">
    </app-footer-type2>
    <app-footer-type3
      *ngIf="configService.defaultOptions.ConfigsNew.FooterType === 'Type3'">
    </app-footer-type3>
    <app-footer-type4
      *ngIf="configService.defaultOptions.ConfigsNew.FooterType === 'Type4'">
    </app-footer-type4>
</div>
```

In condition of "configService.defaultOptions.ConfigsNew.FooterType" it shows corresponding component.

But as My project grows amount of types also grows and I need to keep my code readable and clean. I need to use *ngFor with some condition to show exact component, but names of components are different.

How can I dynamically show component in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that your best bet (if you use components) is use a "dinamic loader component" like show the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader) using [viewContainerRef.createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent)

If only want to show one template or another you can use some like

```
<div class="footer">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
  <ng-template #footer>ONE</ng-template>
  <ng-template #footer>TWO</ng-template>
  <ng-template #footer>THREE</ng-template>
</div>
```

Then gets the "footers"

```
template:TemplateRef<any>  //use a variable to indicate what template 
@ViewChildren('footer') templates:QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>
```

And use some like

```
let index=2
this.template=this.tempaltes.find((_,i)=>i==index)
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srp2mi?file=src%2Fmain.ts)